# Is Nehari manifold a topological manifold?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

Let $X$ be a separable and reflexive Banach space and consider the $C^1$ functional $I:X\to\mathbb{R}$. We define the Nehari manifold corresponding to $I$ by
$$
N=\{u\in X:I'(u)u=0\}.
$$
Then the set $N$ is very useful in the existence theory of PDE's and $N$ is referred to as the Nehari manifold.

I am confused whether $N$ is actually a topological manifold? I guess this is not a manifold. Can someone please confirm with a proper reason.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about this "Nehari manifold", but I would be very surprised if the Nehari *manifold* was not a manifold.

Comment: you might want to modify these tags/or the post: I do not see any pde, Sobolev spaces, elliptic operators

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map
$$
F: X \mapsto \mathbb{R}, u \mapsto \langle I'(u),u \rangle_{X^* \times X}
$$
All you would have to do is show that $0$ is a regular value of $F$, i.e. that it has a surjective differential with splitting kernel if I remember correctly. In order to show that, you need some additional assumptions.